# how to load an LDAP client cert RHEL7 authconfig-tui

Tags: rhel, ldap, certificates

I have a RHEL7 machine that needs to be configured as an LDAP client (user/auth, using `authconfig-tui`).

When finishing `authconfig-tui`, it says, just copy the cert to `/etc/openldap/cacerts`, which I did

```
wget http://path/to/cert.crt -O /etc/openldap/cacerts/cert.crt
```

But when I try to log in with an LDAP user, the `/var/log/messages` says self signed certificate, unknown user, ldap server not found. I can ping the LDAP server.

**Question**: I'm suspecting I can somehow "load" the certificate with `authconfig`(`-tui`?), but how?

Answer (score 0):

After copying the certificate to /etc/openldap/cacerts/, you can try using this command:

```
authconfig --enableldaptls --update
```